# is your turn over after playing an action card and doing what the card says

Tags: fluxx

The Action card "Draw two, play two" says to draw two cards and play them. Then you're supposed to continue your turn.

But isn't your turn already over? Because you've already drawn a card and played the action card and completed the action.

Answer (score 6):

In Fluxx what you do on your turn all depends on what the rules currently are so there is no one clear answer that can be given. If there is a rule in play that requires you to play multiple cards then the card you are talking about counts as just 1 of your actions and you need to continue, if there is not a multiple card play rule in effect then you are probably done.

Comment: To contextualize this answer a bit to the question: ASSUMING the state of the game is the initial "Draw 1 per turn, Play 1 per turn" state, you would be playing the Draw 2 Play 2 action card and then playing and resolving both of the drawn cards AS THE ACTION of the "Draw 2, Play 2" card. If by the effects of these cards the "Play 1 per turn" rule is overridden (by, say, a Play 4 rule card), that comes into effect after the Draw 2 Play 2 card finishes BUT BEFORE YOUR TURN ENDS, so you would still need to play 3 more cards [or, if you don't have that many, the rest of your hand one at a time].

Answer (score 0):

Playing the "Draw Two, Play Two" card counts, in itself, *one play*. Cards that are played as a result of this action do not go towards your Play count for your turn. Similarly, the two cards that are drawn do not go against your Draw count for the turn.

After that, I echo Joe W's answer. Your turn is over based on the current rules after the Action is played; if the rule is still Play 1, then yes, your turn is over. If not, and that Action was not your last play, then your turn is *not* over.